# Make EditText height dynamically adjust

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

The first picture shows an EditText of a fixed size. What I want to have is the height should adjust to fill the the space available above the spinner.

I may increase the the size of the height but I want to be the same for different screen sizes. One more thing I need to note is that I want the feature in the second picture to be preserved. When the keyboard appears, I want the spinner to move up and not be hidden underneath.

Thank you

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/textify" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget37"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="321dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:hint="@string/text_hint"
            android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:overScrollMode="always"
            android:textSize="18sp" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="51dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: fixed size before]

[image: fixed size after]

Comment: I am not sure you can dynamically set the text height in android. What you could do is create different layouts for different device sizes and then set their text heights accordingly in those layouts.

Comment: I'd say you need to play with `fillviewport` and the layour_weight and layout_height (possibly using `match_parent`) of the edittext.

Comment: @njzk2 Your suggestions did work! fillviewport of the ScrollView and match_parent did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Noob here, but I would also recommend using the layout_weight in your linear layout in hopes that the EditText would adjust according to other view elements. Or it wouldn't be hard to switch to a RelativeLayout and link the EditText bottom with the Spinner top.